# Movie/TV set in a single house whose residents have their identical counterparts in another house across the street

Tags: story-identification, movie

Plot:

> Some friends gather for dinner at one of their house. There was some strange natural event that evening which caused a rupture in Time & space. As a result they find out that in an house across street same dinner is taking place with their identical counterparts.

What's the movie or TV series?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's [Coherence](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2866360/) (2013)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(film)) :

> During dinner a blackout occurs. They light candles and Mike provides blue party glow sticks as a light source. The group take a look outside to see if other houses were affected by the power outage and see one house not too far away that has lights on, presumably powered by a generator. Hugh and Amir decide to go to the house to ask if they have a telephone so that Hugh can contact his brother. While they are gone, Mike gets their own home's generator working and power is restored. Hugh and Amir return in some level of distress and confusion. Hugh has an injury to his face and Amir has brought back a box that he found outside the other house because he thought that he saw Hugh drop it - but Hugh protests that he didn't. When the others demand an explanation from Hugh as to what happened, he tells them that when he looked in the window of the other house, he saw **it was set up for dinner exactly like theirs**.

Comment: That's a fun low-budget, high-concept sci-fi movie!